# Regex expression for digit followed by dot (.)

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to find a text with with digit followed by a dot and replace it with the same text (digit with dot) and "xyz" string.
For ex.

```
1. This is a sample
2. test
3. string

**I want to change it to**
1.xyz This is a sample
2.xyz test
3.xyz string
```

I learnt how to find the matching text (\d.) but the challenge is to find the replace with text.
I'm using notepad ++ editor for this, can anyone suggest the "Replace with" string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, you need to escape the dot since it means "match anything (except newline depending if the `s` modifier is set)": `(\d\.)`.

Second, you need to add a quantifier in case you have a 2 digit number or more: `(\d+\.)`.

Third, we don't need group 1 in this case: `\d+\.`.

In the replacement, it's quite simple: just use `$0xyz`. `$0` will refer to group 0 which is the whole match.

[image]

Comment: I tried with above text"$0xyz" but it didn't worked for me. $0 doesn't get replaced with matched string. In short if it searched for "2." then it replaces it with "$0xyz" instead of "2.xyz" which is what I want.

Comment: @sumbad See screenshot, you need to enable Regular expression.

Comment: yes, i did enabled the regular expression. I checked the above text with regular expressions enabled.

Comment: @sumbad Update notepad++. The regex and replacement are correct. This is the last comment.

Comment: I believe the index for the matched groups is 1-based (instead of 0-based)

Comment: @pablete `0` refers to the whole match. `1` refers to group `1` which in this case doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

For notepad++...
You must escape the period/dot character in the expression - [precede it with a backslash](http://www.martinrinehart.com/frontend-engineering/engineers/tools/notepad-pp/search-rep-regex.html):
`\.`

In my case, I needed to find all instances of "{EnvironmentName}.api.mycompany.com"
(dev.api.mycompany.com, stage.api.mycompany.com, prod.api.mycompany, etc.)
I used this search expression:

```
.*\.api.mycompany.com
```

[Notepad++ RegEx Search Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpB56.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think the right answer is as follow:

Find: `^(\d)([.])(\s)`
Replace: `$1$2XYZ`

That will work with "n. " being "n" a digit [0-9]. If the input should accept digits with different lengths like 10, 100, 1000... or multiples dots "." after the digit or multiple spaces after the dot, then the answer is:

Find: `^(\d*)([.])([.]*)(\s*)`
Replace: `$1$2XYZ`

Input:

```
1. This is a sample
2. test
3. string
30. string
10..... string
50005...     string
```

Output:

```
1.XYZ This is a sample
2.XYZ test
3.XYZ string
30.XYZ string
10.XYZ string
50005.XYZ string
```

Comment: What is the added value to the valid other answer?